# Is there any point using RVM gemsets with mod_rails (passenger)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger

I have created a .rvmrc file in the parent directory where my app is located, and inside it placed:

`rvm ruby-1.9.3-p327@ruby-1.9.3-p327-project_name`

and in my deploy.rb file (I am using Capistrano) I have:

`set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p327@ruby-1.9.3-p327-project_name'`

However am I right in thinking that the current stable version of Passenger can't use independent gemsets per app anyway? So I might as well not have bothered doing the above? Or is it good to have it in place for when Passenger 4 comes out? Are there any downsides to keep it? Should I remove these references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

current passenger does not support different rubies, support for different rubies is easily added with this documentation: https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/